# Convert a string to the character that it represents

Tags: c, flex-lexer

```c
const char *lex1 = "\'a\'";   // prints 'a'
const char *lex2 = "\'\\t\'"; // prints '\t'
const char *lex3 = "\'0\'";   // prints '0'
```

How would I convert from a `char *` to the representative `char`? For the above example, the conversion is as follows:

```c
char lex1_converted = 'a';
char lex2_converted = '\t';
char lex3_converted = '0';
```

I am currently thinking of chains of `if-else` blocks, but there might be a better approach.

This is a homework problem related to lexical analysis with `flex`. Please provide the minimum hint required to comprehend the solution. Thanks!

**Edit:** Looks like I misinterpreted the tokenized strings in my first post :)

Comment: Considering you have extra single quotes in your strings, the character you want is the second character of the string, right? So just use an index

Comment: @UnholySheep so if there was a string like `"'\t'"`, the second character would give `'\t'`, not `'\'`, right?

Comment: Yes, because `\t` is a special escape character, so it is one `char`

Comment: @UnholySheep I misinterpreted the tokenized strings in my first post, I edited it now :)

Comment: There's no need to backslash-escape apostrophes in C strings. `"'"` is fine. Backslashes and double-quotes need to be escaped. If you're supposed to use Flex, you'll need to write patterns recognising the escape sequences you're supposed to handle. Chains of if-else blocks are an indication that you haven't cone to grips with the concept of regular-expression-based lexical analysis. You'll also need to ensure that you understand basic C concepts related to characters and "strings".

Answer (score 1):

```
const char* lex1="your sample text";
char lex1_converted=*lex1;
```

this code will convert the first char of your lex1 , and if you want to convert others you had to do this

```
char lex1_converted=*(lex1+your_disire_index);
//example
char lex1_converted=*(lex1+1);
```

and also the other way is doing this

```
char lex1_converted=lex1[your_desire_index];
```

Answer (score 1):

> Please provide the minimum hint required to comprehend the solution.

A key attribute of the conversion is to detect that the source string may lack the expected format.

Below some untested sample code to get OP started.

**Sorry, did not see "homework problem related to lexical analysis with flex" until late.**
Non-flex, C only approach:
Pseudo code

```
// Return 0-255 on success
// Else return -1.
int swamp_convert(s)
  Find string length
  If length too small or string missing the two '
    return fail
  if s[1] char is not \
    if length is 3, return middle char
    return fail

  if length is 4 & character after \ is a common escaped character, (search a string)
    return corresponding value (table lookup)

   Maybe consider octal, hexadecimal, other escaped forms

   else return fail
```

> ```
>  // Return 0-255 on success
>
>  // Else return -1.
>
>  int swamp_convert(const char *s) {
>
>    size_t len = strlen(s);
>
>    if (len < 3 || s[0] != '\'' || s[len - 1] != '\'') {
>
>      return -1;
>
>    }
>
>    if (s[1] != '\\') {
>
>      return (len == 3) ? s[1] : -1;
>
>    }
>
>
>
>    // Common escaped single charters
>
>    const char *escape_chars = "abtnvfr\\\'\"";
>
>    const char *e = strchr(escape_chars, s[2]);
>
>    if (t && len == 4) {
>
>      return "\a\b\t\n\v\f\r\\\'\""[e - escape_chars];
>
>    }
>
>
>
>    // Additional code to handle \0-7, \x, \X, maybe \e ...
>
>
>
>    return -1;
>
>  }
> ```